# Delete specified array from firebase database

Tags: javascript, json, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to delete the item2 if i choose the delete button of item2.

```
 {
      "items" : {
        "category1" : {
          "item" : {
            "0" : {
              "name" : "item1",
            },
            "1" : {
              "name" : "item2",
            },
            "2" : {
              "name" : "item3",
            }
          }
        },
        "category2" : {
          "item" : {
            "0" : {
              "name" : "item1",
            }
          }
        }
}
```

I tried with this code:

```
removeItem: function (item, category) {
        db.ref('items').child(category1).child('item').child(item['.key']).remove()
      },
```

Anybody see what i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
removeItem: function (category, itemId) {
        db.ref('items').child(category).child('item').child(itemId).remove()
      }
```

Considering: `category` is `"category1"` and `itemId` is `"1"`.

So, the function will be called as: `removeItem("category1", "1")` // to delete "item2"